# VBA update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Below query is resulting zero rows updated

but i am sure that there is a record to update

```
DoCmd.RunSQL (" Update tbltesting set IsDiff ='Yes' " & _
                "where empid= " & Me.txtEmpId.Value & _
                " and testid= " & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & ";")
```

Please help!!

Comment: If you want to receive good answers to your questions, I suggest you not post them multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this as a check to make sure your fields have the data that you think they have:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL (" SELECT * FROM tbltesting " & _
                "WHERE empid= " & Me.txtEmpId.Value & _
                " and testid= " & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & ";")
```

Incidentally, you can leave off the .Value portion.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you got it straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need single quotes around the WHERE parameters:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL (" Update tbltesting set IsDiff ='Yes' where empid= '" & Me.txtEmpId.Value & "' and testid= '" & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "';")
```

Comment: No, we've already covered this in the OPs original thread. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **.Value**  and **;** If it still not updating then change 'Yes' to 1.

You can also try Yes without single quotes.

Comment: The value of True in Access and Jet/ACE is -1, not 1. However, using 1 here actually does work when appending to a Boolean field, because True (-1) is really defined as Not False. I would use True without quotes if I were writing this SQL.

Comment: "Boolean field" -- oxymoron. SQL data types can be NULL and the Access database engine's YESNO data type is no exception. Three value logic does not equal Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode cut and paste the delete statement with  the actual values into whatever database development environment you are using - run the query in the data base this will tell you if there is a syntax problem or data problem