# VBA select not returning any rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax

Below query is not returning any rows into the listbox.There is no error message:

```
lstDiff.RowSource = "select TestScenario,TestId from tblTesting where empid= '" & Me.txtEmpId.Value & "' and testid= '" & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "'"
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, whenever I use SQL statements in code, I prefer to store the statement in a variable. While testing, on the line after you assign your statement to a variable, you can use Debug.Print to see what your SQL statement looks like after parsing your txtempid and txtautonumber. It would look something like this.

```
Dim sSQL as String
sSQL = "select TestScenario,TestId from tblTesting where empid= '" & Me.txtEmpId.Value & "' and testid= '" & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "'"
Debug.Print sSQL
lstDiff.RowSource = sSQL
```

Then as long as your immediate window is visible (Ctrl-G), you can see what your SQL statement really is. If it looks right in the immediate window, copy and paste it into the query builder and run it there.

Answer (score 2):

Your values in the field are numeric, so the extra single quotes aren't needed.  Code should look like the following:

```
Me.lstDiff.RowSource = "select TestScenario,TestId from tblTesting where empid= " & Me.txtEmpId & " and testid= " & Me.txtAutoNumber & ";"
```

I've also dropped .Value from the field references, they're not harmful, but also aren't necessary.

And I've added a semi-colon to the end of your statement.

Depending on when/where you insert this code, you may need to add the following statement as well:

```
Me.lstDiff.Requery
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep posting questions about the exact same WHERE clause with exactly the same apparent error in each one. SO users dutifully point out your error and then a few days later, you show up with a related question utilizing the same faulty WHERE clause.

[DLookup Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125380/dlookup-problem):

```
  txtContSunStart1.Value = DLookup("Start1", "tblContract", _
     "TestId = " & _
     lstResults.Value & _
     "" And "Day = 'Sunday'")
```

[VBA Update Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166283/vba-update-query):

```
  DoCmd.RunSQL (" Update tbltesting set IsDiff ='Yes' where empid= " & Me.txtEmpId.Value & " and testid= " & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & ";")
```

[VBA SQL Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165192/vba-sql-problem)

```
  DoCmd.RunSQL ("insert into tbltesting (IsDiff)values ('Yes') where empid= '" & Me.txtEmpId.Value & "' and testid= '" & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "'")
```

And then in the current question:

```
  lstDiff.RowSource = "select TestScenario,TestId from tblTesting where empid= '" & Me.txtEmpId.Value & "' and testid= '" & Me.txtAutoNumber.Value & "'"
```

You are having difficulties with exactly the same set of problems repeatedly.

Here are the rules for concatenating SQL strings with the correct delimiters in Access:

1. numeric values do not need delimiters:

   "... AND testid= " & Me!txtAutoNumber
2. text values need quote delimiters. In Access, it's general practice to use double quotes, but much easier to use single quotes since it's a pain to type double quotes in a form that will work (typing """ or """" depending on context is counterintuitive and silly to me, so I always define a global constant that holds the double quote symbol and concatenate with that).

   "... AND textfield=" & Chr(34) & Me!MyTextField & Chr(34)
3. date values use the # delimiter:

   "... AND datefield=#" & Me!MyDateField & "#"
4. Boolean fields require no quotes and it works best to use True and False:

   "... AND IsDiff=True"

These rules apply both to WHERE clause criteria and to SET statements in UPDATE queries. The rules apply in writing a SQL string that you pass to DoCmd.RunSQL or CurrentDB.Execute, as well as to writing SQL strings to be used as the recordsource of a form or report or as the rowsource of a combo box or listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query in your SQL Management Studio. Do you get any row(s) back?

Edit: Just noticed the access-tag. Are you sure your table contains at least one post with supplied ids?

Comment: Yes the below query is resulting one row :
SELECT TestScenario, TestId
FROM tblTesting
WHERE empid=22222222 And testid=131;

Comment: Has been years since I used VBA. But, can you "alert" the result with MsgBox()? Using another object than listbox. Have you selected the right database?

Answer (score 0):

My Access is a bit rusty, but if all else fails try using a recordset to capture the data from the SQL and loop through it adding the values to the list box. [Example Code](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_ado_populate_list.html)